# Speed of sound in air experiment without measuring internal diameter

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, acoustics

Experiment details: https://prnt.sc/GtiGLOq4Ocsk

The equation $c = \lambda \cdot f$ is for the speed of sound in a medium. When doing an experiment by adjusting the length of a column of air, the equation becomes $c = 4f(l+0.3d)$. The idea is that if you don't want to measure the internal diameter of the tube, you can subtract the following:

$l$ is the distance from the top of the water in the graduated cylinder to the top of the resonance tube.

$l_1$ is the first time that a loud noise is heard.

$l_2$ is the second time it is heard.

$d$ is the internal diameter of the tube.

$$l_1 + 0.3d = \frac{\lambda}{4}$$
$$l_2 + 0.3d = \frac{3\lambda}{4}  $$

When we subtract the $l_2$ equation from the $l_1$ equation, we achieve the equation:
$$2(l_2-l_1) = \lambda$$
So the speed of sound in air is simply $$ 2(l_2-l_1) \cdot f$$

My question is that which frequency would I use in this table of values? I tried the fundamental frequency but it gave me an answer far away from the answer that I expected $(340m/s)$.

This is the table:
$$f(hz) = 512, 427, 341$$
$$l(mm) = 153, 192, 237$$

Comment: You have a lot of symbols. Could you please write in your question, what $l$, $l_1$, $l_2$, and $d$ mean? In addition, could you please describe your experiment in greater detail?

Comment: @David I have fixed this now, thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: I think the point of the experiment is that you have to measure two distances, $l_1$ and $l_2$, for each frequency. Right now, in your table (if I understand correctly), you have gotten $l_1$ for each frequency, but did not measure $l_2$. Is this the case?

Comment: Oh lol. I see now. Thanks a lot, I had assumed that $l_2$ was the value which I now realise is $l_1$ of the NEXT frequency. So what I must do is measure $l_2$ of the $512$ Hz thing and THEN apply that formula. Cheers.

Comment: You need a tube long enough to find the 1st and 2nd harmonics with the same frequency.

Comment: @photon, are you determined to find the speed of sound with a resonance tube, or are you open to a different method that is definitely low tech but very easy to understand and surprisingly more accurate than it would seem?

Comment: Sure I'm open to ideas - however I will have to learn the resonant tube method anyway as it's the one required on the school syllabus.